# Access is denied deleting files at command prompt

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file nightly to delete files in a certain directory that are older than 15 days. I am getting "Access is denied" even if I paste the command into an elevated (admin) command prompt window. This is on a Windows 7 PC. Here is the command that I found online to delete files over a certain age:

```
forfiles /p "C:\ProgramData\WEBSERVER\Download\X549D95" /d -15 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

The user I am logged in as is a local administrator and has full control to the files in that folder. The PC is not a member of the domain so should not have group policies doing anything weird on it.

Maybe I have to do something to make this part of the command run as an administrator: `"cmd /c del @path"`? If so, how do I do that? I cannot find a switch for "cmd" to do that.

Comment: Do you schedule the task using scheduler or manually run the batch each night?

Comment: It's scheduled with task scheduler however I am getting the access denied when trying to run the command manually at the command prompt.

Comment: The reason I posted here and put "batch-file" as the topic is because I am wondering if the problem is that this command "cmd /c del @path" doesn't have enough rights in my command to run as an administrator. I've Googled trying to figure out how to give it administrative rights and cannot find an answer. I have given the user I am logged on as full rights to the files in the folder so don't see how it could be an issue with NTFS permissions. Here is my entire command and even if I run it manually at the command prompt, not in a batch file, I get access denied:

Comment: forfiles /p "C:\ProgramData\WEBSERVER\Download\X549D95" /d -15 /c "cmd /c del @path"

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. The files are being written to disk by the camera software and created as read-only. So I have to change the read-only attribute to be able to delete them.